# Занесение пути к файлу в переменную c++

Tags: c++, linux

Всем привет, такой вопрос, я получаю путь к файлу в переменную и далее мне нужно ее использовать для открытия файла, как мне это сделать?

```
string path = "/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-4/4-004c/hwmon/" + var1 + "/pwm1";

ofstream file51;
file51.open(path);
if (file51.is_open())
{
    cout << "qwe"<<endl;
file51 << 255;
}
file51.close();
```

Comment: Вы именно это и делаете в приведённом вами примере кода.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да,но это не работает=)

Comment: Что именно означает "не работает"? При запуске программы компьютер превращается в тыкву?

Comment: Посмотрите, есть ли вообще такой файл (и какие у него права) в вашей системе.

Comment: @avp  да файл есть,путь верный,с правами тоже все хорошо,при компиляции выдает ошибку в строке file51.open(path)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ошибку при компиляции выдает в строке file51.open(path)

Comment: Значит у вас С++98 и `string` не подходит. Используйте `char *`

Comment: @avp щас только сам дошел file51.open(path.c_str());

Comment: Сторонний комментарий: почему вы не идёте по пути */sys/class/hwmon/*? https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/sysfs-interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string var1;
// some code
string path = "/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-4/4-004c/hwmon/" + var1 + "/pwm1";
ofstream file51(path.c_str());
```

Comment: угу,именно так=)

Answer (score -1):

Укажите расширение файла, например:

```
string path = "/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-4/4-004c/hwmon/" + var1 + "/pwm1.txt";
```

Comment: Да нет, это вообще здесь не при чем=)